# Remove Repeated Values in LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql-server, left-join

My SQL string is as follows:

```
SELECT d.*, a.*
FROM Documents AS d 
LEFT JOIN [Document_Attachments] AS a
ON  d.[Doc No Int] = a.[Document Number]
AND d.[Revision] = a.[Document Revision]
WHERE (d.[Lock] = 'off' 
AND d.[Status] <> 'DELETED') 
OR (d.[Lock] = 'off' 
AND d.[Status] IS NULL)
ORDER BY d.[Filename] ASC
```

This retrieves all the information I require, but also shows duplicates of Table "d" if more than one match is found.

I just need any one match to be retrieved so I know a value exists.

E.g.

Table d:

```
Doc No Int  Rev
E-0100      0
E-0200      0
E-0300      0
```

Table a:

```
Document Number     Document Revision   Attachment ID
E-0100              0                   27
E-0100              0                   28
E-0200              0                   46
E-0300              0                   100
E-0300              0                   101
```

Information retrieved (I've removed most rows for this example):

```
Doc No Int  Rev  Attachment ID
E-0100      0    27
E-0100      0    28
E-0200      0    46
E-0300      0    100
E-0300      0    101
```

What I would like to be retrieved:

```
Doc No Int  Rev  Attachment ID
E-0100      0    27
E-0200      0    46
E-0300      0    100
```

So it doesn't really matter which of the "Attachment ID" values is retrieved, I just need to fill the column with a value or a *NULL* if no match found.

I hope that makes sense.

Thank you.

Comment: if you add select distinct? (SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name)

Comment: so you only want the rows that have the smallest `Attachment ID` for a given `Document Number`?

Comment: Thanks for posting guys, Gordon's answer below sorted me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only one column from the attachments, I would suggest a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT d.*,
       (SELECT TOP 1 Attachment_Id
        FROM Document_Attachments a
        WHERE d.[Doc No Int] = a.[Document Number] AND
              d.[Revision] = a.[Document Revision]
       )
FROM Documents d
WHERE (d.[Lock] = 'off' AND d.[Status] <> 'DELETED') OR
      (d.[Lock] = 'off' AND d.[Status] IS NULL)
ORDER BY d.[Filename] ASC;
```

If you want more than one column, you can use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT d.*, a.*
FROM Documents d CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 a.*
      FROM Document_Attachments a
      WHERE d.[Doc No Int] = a.[Document Number] AND
            d.[Revision] = a.[Document Revision]
     ) a
WHERE (d.[Lock] = 'off' AND d.[Status] <> 'DELETED') OR
      (d.[Lock] = 'off' AND d.[Status] IS NULL)
ORDER BY d.[Filename] ASC;
```

You can also do what you want by adding a `group by` to your original query or using `row_number()` in a subquery, but I think these are easier solutions.

Comment: Gordon Linoff you absolute god! Thank you so much, the first one worked perfectly! Really appreciate you taking the time to post your response. Life saver.